# How to fill a hole in textured mesh without getting weird faces?

Tags: modeling, texturing

I am new in blender and have have struggled a bit with filling holes in my textured mesh made in photoscan. I am writing here because I haven't been able to find similar examples on the internet.

The thing is that I want to remove certain elements in my environment, which goes well. But when I want to fill the hole that gets creating when deleting these elements, I run into problem.

Most of the time when I try to fill the hole, these crazy striped faces get created(see attached file). This happens both when I fill the hole in one go with the "F" key or if I close it together face by face.

Sometimes when I close the hole, it is closed properly, but with untextured faces (see attached file). Here I dont know how to add texture to just a specific little spot on the otherwise textured model.

Anyone that can help my here?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am at work right now so can't provide full answer, but from look of it you would need to unwrap the newly added plane so it will know which pixels from texture it should use.

Comment: When you change the topology of a mesh it changes the UV. As @internetofmine states you will need to unwrap again to get the textures to fit. It may not make much sense with a tiny hole but imagine a globe with a country missing and then adding faces to fill the hole. The new faces cannot know what the country texture should be and just stretches from its known existing edges.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I will try to unwrap it then. Any tips to how I do this in the best way?